# Sidekiq Scheduler - Rails - Run a Worker On 2nd of every Month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sidekiq-cron

Using sidekiq-scheduler, how can we schedule a worker to run 2nd of every month  on a specified time?

```
import_worker:
  every: '0 0 * 1 *'
  class: ImportWorker
  queue: scheduler
  enabled: true
```

Will the above cron run every one month? Also how can I specify time here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `cron`, not `every`. [`cron` format](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) is minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week. `0 0 * 1 *` says to run every day of January at midnight. To run on the 2nd of every month at 12:30 would be `30 12 2 * *`.

```
import_worker:
  cron: '30 12 2 * *'
  class: ImportWorker
  queue: scheduler
```

Comment: this site is useful as well https://cron.help. :)